# Start New Activity if Retrofit Returns No Data To Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I am calling data from server using Retrofit to a Recyclerview.
I want to go to new activity if empty data is returned from retrofit. Below is the code i have tried.

```
  ApiInterface apiInterface = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiInterface2.class);
        Call<List<ImageList>> call = apiInterface.getImgData(userEmail);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ImageList>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ImageList>> call, Response<List<ImageList>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        imageLists = response.body();
                        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MyListings.this);
                        //layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MyListings.this, 2);
                        rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                        adapter = new ListingsAdapter(imageLists, MyListings.this);
                        rv.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(rv.getContext(), layoutManager.getOrientation()));
                        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MyListings.this, NoDataHereActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } } }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<ImageList>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MyListings.this, "Failed!!" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            } });
```

Comment: is your response body actually null? It might simply be empty.

Comment: Actually that's what i want.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by applying this code.

```
  ApiInterface apiInterface = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiInterface2.class);
        Call<List<ImageList>> call = apiInterface.getImgData(userEmail);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ImageList>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ImageList>> call, Response<List<ImageList>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body() != null && !response.body().isEmpty()) {
                        imageLists = response.body();
                        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MyListings.this);
                        //layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MyListings.this, 2);
                        rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                        adapter = new ListingsAdapter(imageLists, MyListings.this);
                        rv.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(rv.getContext(), layoutManager.getOrientation()));
                        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    } else {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MyListings.this, NoDataHereActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } } }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<ImageList>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MyListings.this, "Failed!!" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            } });
```